# Where can I find fonts for my game?

Tags: assets, fonts

Where can I find fonts (preferably free, but a reasonable fee is acceptable) that I can use in my for-pay/commericial game?

Comment: Also related to font-searching (although definitely a different question): http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/360/where-can-i-find-fonts-which-i-can-distribute-with-an-open-source-game

Comment: [https://fontlibrary.org](https://fontlibrary.org) has a lot of open source fonts. You might be able to use some of those, depending on licensing and the opinions of lawyers. :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can find many free and cheap fonts on [MyFonts.com](http://new.myfonts.com/), including the [Larabie Font Collection](http://new.myfonts.com/foundry/Larabie/) (many of which are free for commercial use)

Comment: +1 for MyFonts because they have a "what languages does this font support" search feature.

Answer (score 11):

Two good places to find free fonts are [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) and [The League of Moveable Type](http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/).

Answer (score 5):

If you're building a web game, Google has provided free fonts here: https://www.google.com/fonts This is a great service for web developers, because web licenses for fonts can be a gray area.  They have only a small fraction of the fonts you can find on sites like others have suggested, however.

Answer (score 4):

I always head to [dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com/), although the range is similar to Font Squirrel and MyFonts.

Answer (score 3):

The [League of Movable Type](http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/) has a few fonts for free use, under a [very permissive license](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell these XNA fonts from Microsoft are free to use (released under the [MS-PL](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/ms-pl.html)):

[Redistributable Font Pack](http://creators.xna.com/en-GB/contentpack/fontpack)

Comment: Can those fonts be used in non XNA games? The site is not clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts from [Canada Type](http://new.myfonts.com/foundry/Canada_Type/) have a reasonable license, and I plan on using at least one of theirs in my next iPhone game.