# Where can I find True Type fonts that are free for commercial use?

Tags: legal, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find fonts for my game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/where-can-i-find-fonts-for-my-game)

Does anyone know of fonts that are true type and unicode that can be used in a commercial game for free?

Comment: also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/360/where-can-i-find-fonts-which-i-can-distribute-with-an-open-source-game

Comment: Possibly not duplicated. Licensing changes the nature of the question ("Can use for my game" could be royalty based, "Which fonts for FOSS game" includes fonts with a viral license).

Comment: Isn't that just a matter of checking the licensing on the fonts that you search through on the various sites listed in the linked question.